Variable declaration returns compiler error: Expected user-defined type, not project
Trying to search for partial words and numbers in Outlook.
Dim strSearch As String is returning a compiler error.

Expected user-defined type, not project

Tried several versions of this on newest version of Outlook.
Sub AdvSearchForStr()
    On Error GoTo Err_SearchFolderForSender
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = InputBox("Enter String to AdvSearch", "Advanced Search")

    strTo = "Test"

    Dim strDASLFilter As String
    strDASLFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" & strSearch & "%'"

    Debug.Print strDASLFilter

    Dim strScope As String
    strScope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items', 'Tasks'"

    Dim objSearch As Search <------ THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
    Set objSearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strScope, Filter:=strDASLFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="SearchFolder")

    'Save the search results to a searchfolder
    objSearch.Save (strSearch)

    Set objSearch = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_SearchFolderForSender:
    MsgBox "Error # " & Err & " : " & Error(Err)

End Sub


What weird error is it returning?

Thought I had linked the image! on the line 'Dim objSearch as Search' it prompts that there is a compile error, expected user-defined type, not project

And the code is in Outlook?  I tried it - it didn't seem to work, but didn't give me any errors.  objSearch variable was created though.

Yeah ive added the code using VB in outlook under a module, its meant to return a prompt to search for partial words but it gives that error mentioned instead

Appears to indicate you named your project "Search".

Not sure how I missed that, tysm, its working now!
